# How to get rid of diagonal in R

Tags: r

Below is my r-script for normalizing the data set and then finding euclidean distances using dist().

```
    normalize_data <-  function (wine_data1)
      {
        feature_mat <- (wine_data1[,2:14]) #first column is class label hence normalizing only features                              
        #print(feature_mat)
        min_vector=apply(feature_mat, 2, min)
        max_vector=apply(feature_mat, 2, max)
        feature_mat <- sweep(feature_mat, 2, min_vector, FUN="-") 
        feature_mat =sweep(feature_mat, 2,  min_vector-max_vector, FUN="/")
        distance_mat <- dist(feature_mat, method = "euclidean", diag = FALSE, upper= FALSE)
        closest_dist <- apply(distance,1,min)
        return(closest_dist)
      }
    normdata <-normalize_data(winedata)
    normdata1 <- cbind(winedata[,1],normdata) #here i am binding the class labels with the normalized data


My euclidean distance matrix looks like below:
[1, 0, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4]
[1, 1.2, 0, 3.4, 5.1]
[2, 1.3, 1.7, 0, 3.4]
[2, 1.4, 1.9, 2.0, 0]
```

The first column is the class label. For each row I want to find only one row that has the lesser distance. 
So I want something like this:

[class label1, classlabel2, minvalue]

classlabel1 is the label of first point and classlabel2 is the label of the row(point) with which the distance is minimum and minvalue is the smallest distance between one point and other

But when I do apply(dist_mat, 1, min) I get all zeros.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
    Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please provide the expected output for the euclidean distance matrix you provided?

Comment: [1, 2, 0.234]  # first element is class label of the first point which I used for calculating euclidean distance, second element in class label of the closest point,  third element is the distance itself

Comment: Please use the "edit" link under your question to edit the complete expected output for this example into the question itself.

Comment: Also, where did 0.234 come from? That value doesn't appear in the data you included in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you are asking you just need to do the following:

```
mat<- matrix(c(0,1,3,4,
           3,0,2,4,
           1,2,0,6,
           4,8,2,0),ncol=4,byrow=T,dimnames =list(c("R1","R2","R3","R4"),
                                                  c("C1","C2","C3","C4")))

apply(mat,1,function(x)colnames(mat)[order(x)[2]])
```

and you will get the column's name with the minimum that is not zero:

```
 R1   R2   R3   R4 
"C2" "C3" "C1" "C3"
```

Comment: That worked but I need class label of that minimum value. As I mentioned my distance matrix has class label in the first column. You can see the code that I used cbind() to combine the class label after calculating the distances. Is it at least possible to get the index/position of the minimum distance??

Comment: @laxmi23 I just turned off my computer,I am on my phone right now so I don't if it will work, but try this: colnames(mat)[which.min (x[x>0])] instead of just min() in the apply

Comment: It doesn't work. It gets the indexes from 1 to num of rows. But I want the index of that particular value. Suppose for row1, I found the minimum value at 10th column then I need that position.

Comment: @laxmi23 I updated my answer, now we have what you are looking for